# how to store data in array in ng-boostrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

**alldetails.ts**

```js
import { Details } from './details';

export const ALLDETAILS: Details[] = [];
```

how to store the json data in these Alldetails array  from any component.ts;

Comment: `ALLDETAILS = your data from json`

Comment: but is not storing the data

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/table-complete.ts

Comment: here is the example but the data is manually entered in courties,i need that how to store the data from table-complete.ts to contries.ts

Comment: mandy, looking into this question, I feel you need to finish some courses on software development and javascript first.